# Function output not printing?

Tags: python, function

trying to see whether the functions work, I tried printing out to see whether the random list could be sorted, however nothing seems to be printed. Also how would I measure the time it takes to sort the list out?

```
import random
import time
def mergeSort(mylist):
    if len(mylist) <= 1:
        return mylist
        mid = len(mylist) // 2
        left = mergeSort(mylist[:mid])
        right = mergeSort(mylist[mid:])
        return merge(left,right)


def merge(left,right):
    if not left:
        return right
    if not right:
        return left
    if left[0] < right[0]:
        return [left[0]]+merge(left[1:],right)
    else:
        return [right[0]]+merge(left,right[1:])
newList=[]
for i in range(100):
    newList.append(random.randint(1,1000))



val = mergeSort(newList)
print (val)
```

Nothing is outputted, why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You blew your indentation.  Here's the correct version:

```
def mergeSort(mylist):
    if len(mylist) <= 1:
        return mylist
    mid = len(mylist) // 2
    left = mergeSort(mylist[:mid])
    right = mergeSort(mylist[mid:])
    return merge(left,right)
```

In the version you posted, you have the main body of the routine still inside the **if** statement, but after the **return**.  This means that it can never execute.  If you look, you should find that your program *did* print something, the value **None**.